# Soundcloud X-Cache: Error from cloudfront while trying to get access token

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to get access token from Soundcloud API with grant_type set to password. I am sending the following details
client_id, client_secret, username and password. The response I am getting is

> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
>
> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>
> Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
>
> Content-Length: 25
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Date: Wed, 01 Aug 2018 08:29:51 GMT
>
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type,
>   Origin
>
> Status: 401 Unauthorized
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> Server: am/2
>
> X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
>
> Via: 1.1 416969cc5e55e474a7175a8a456955b0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
>
> X-Amz-Cf-Id: H7PZsVdf58pDwc9k5_nZBl-fS1f9bS-frNrtDSHNPr1bOMYLaVJWgA==
>
> {"error":"invalid_grant"}

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: API is dead, they are not accepting new apps. needed access for my FYP but out of luck:(